# Docusign REST call from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, docusignapi

I'm trying to call the DocuSign REST login information within a CodeIgniter application.  The Docusign sample code shows:

```
// Input your info here:
$integratorKey = '...';
$email = '...@....com';
$password = '...';
$name = 'John Doe';

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}
```

I keep getting a status response of 0.  When I echo out the curl all the xml tags have been converted to lowercase (which won't work with Docusign).  Has anyone done this call within CodeIgniter?  How did you accomplish it?  I know my credentials are good because I can do a command line curl and get a response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what CodeIgniter is doing and why the tags would be converted to lower case but you're right in that DocuSign expects xml tags to begin with a capital letter so that might not work.  What you can do, though, is use JSON headers and request bodies instead.

For instance, instead of an XML formatted authentication header like

```
<DocuSignCredentials>
  <Username>username</Username>
  <Password>password</Password>
  <IntegratorKey>integrator_key</IntegratorKey>
</DocuSignCredentials>
```

You could use the corresponding JSON auth header like

```
{
    "Username": "username",
    "Password": "password",
    "IntegratorKey": "integrator_key"
}
```

The "nodes" still start with a capital but since it's not xml I'm wondering if CodeIgniter maybe leaves it alone.  Examples of this can be found at the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/) on [this page](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call).